# "Вроде как" в начале предложения

Tags: пунктуация

Писал предыдущий вопрос и сразу возник новый. Хотел написать "Вроде как(,) это уточнение..." Но озадачился: выделяется запятой "вроде как" в данном случае или нет?
И снова спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ВРОДЕ КАК - это разговорная частица со значением "по-видимому, вероятно, наверное".

"Это вроде как (как бы, будто бы) уточнение". Здесь знаков препинания нет.

"Вроде как, это уточнение". Думаю, что инверсия позволяет нам считать "вроде как" вводным словом (по значению и по месту в предложении), но в источниках прямого указания на этот вариант не находится.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно "Словарю вводных слов" разговорная частица *вроде как* редко бывает вводным словом. Встречаются случаи только авторского (то есть в художественной литературе) использования ее в качестве вводного слова в модальном значении «неуверенность, предположение», интонационно выделяется: *Она, вроде как, к маме твоей заходила (С. Лукьяненко)*. Не рекомендуется использовать ее в качестве вводного слова. Обычно невводное, употребляется в функции модальной частицы со значением неуверенности, не обособляется.

То есть эта частица сама по себе выражает значение неуверенности, и делать из нее вводное слово с точки зрения смысла нецелесообразно (нового смыслового оттенка не появляется). Только принудительное интонационное выделение, характерное для прерывистой речи, может сделать эту частицу вводным словом. Но такие ситуации наиболее вероятны в художественной литературе для характеристики персонажа (например, чтобы передать взволнованность или испуг, сопровождающиеся "спотыканием" в речи). Обычно же мы произносим эту частицу плавно, без акцентированных пауз.

Comment: Как известно, большинство вводных слов могут иметь другие функции, то есть быть обстоятельством, сказуемым, частицей, союзом и т.д. Полагаться на интонацию при обособлении вводных слов чаще всего нельзя - дело в том, что интонационная структура предложения обычно выражает более важные синтаксические отношения. Но как же тогда определяется "вводность" для конкретного выражения? В любом случае, не стоит ее однозначно "назначать, запрещать, рекомендовать и считать целесообразным", но нужно провести анализ.

Comment: Во-первых, важна тематика, в нашем случае вполне подходящая, но такое же значение могут иметь модальные частицы. Во-вторых, важна структура предложения:  вводные слова не связаны синтаксически с другими словами и их можно изъять из предложения или переставить.В приведенном примере "Она, вроде как, к маме твоей заходила" всё говорит о том, что перед нами типично вводное слово, даже если оно не обозначено в словарях. Интонация: Она, вроде как, к мАме (повышение тона)твоей заходИла (понижение тона). Вводное слово интонационно не выделяется.

Comment: Это предложение можно написать без запятых и произнести без пауз: Она вроде как к маме твоей заходила. А можно с паузами и запятыми. В тех случаях, когда речь идет об авторских вводных словах, которые обычно вводными не являются, критерием различения как раз служат паузы. По крайней мере, эта закономерность прослеживается в Словаре.

Comment: 1).Смысл у предложений разный. При отсутствии обособления "она заходила" - это факт, а предположение делается "насчет мамы". При обособлении мы не уверены, что она вообще заходила. 2)И еще раз об интонации. Любое высказывание состоит из отдельных фраз нисходящего или восходящего тона, разделенными паузами различной длительности. Вводные слова чаще всего не составляют отдельной фразы, поэтому мы не можем выделять их паузами. Обособление вводных слов обычно соответствует грамматическому, а не интонационному принципу.